# Filtering grid with QueryReadStore

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a grid wich store is a QueryReadStore. It works fine, even the virtual scrolling.
The problem is the filter, when I filter, it generates a strange URL like this:

```
http://mydomain:8080/project=%3F&1=f&2=i&3=l&4=t&5=e&6=r&7=......
```

And I want to looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/project?filter={%22op%22:%22contains%22,%22data%22:[{%22op%22:%22string%22,%22data%22:%22username%22,%22isCol%22:true},{%22op%22:%22string%22,%22data%22:%22s%22,%22isCol%22:false}]}
```

Here is the code that generates the grid and the filter:

```
this.grid = new EnhancedGrid({ 
                store: null,
                structure: this.columns,         
                rowsPerPage: 20, 
                autoHeight: false, 
                plugins: {
                    filter: {
                        closeFilterbarButton: false,
                        isServerSide: true,
                        setupFilterQuery: dojo.hitch(this, function(commands, request){
                          if(commands.filter && commands.enable){
                              var gridStoreURL = this.grid.store.url;

                              if(gridStoreURL.indexOf("?") > -1) {
                                request.query = "&filter=" + JSON.stringify(commands.filter);
                              } else {
                                request.query = "?filter=" + JSON.stringify(commands.filter);
                              }
                          }else{
                          }
                        }),
                        ruleCount: 3,
                        itemsName: "logs",
                        disabledConditions: {anycolumn : this.disabledFilterAnyColumn}
                    }
                }
            }, this.idGridContainer);
```

I create the store with this function:

```
var store = dojox.data.QueryReadStore({
                url : this.urlBase + agentId,
                requestMethod:"get"
            });

            this.grid.setStore(store, null, null);
```

When I use JsonStore to create the store, the filter works fine, but with this doesn't.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be attempting to set the store query to a string, but IIRC `QueryReadStore` only ever expects the query to be passed as an object, as opposed to `JsonRestStore` which can accept it either way.

Try something like this instead, for starters, and see if it gets you further:

```
request.query = { filter: JSON.stringify(commands.filter) }
```